# Load testing web UI

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, load-testing

I want to test 500 users using my web app at the same time.

I have looked into running Selenium Web Driver in parallel or using JMeter Web Driver but I've seen others advise to only run ~5 of these at one time on one machine.

Is there a viable way to test what I want on one machine (or at least fewer than 100)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 types of testing you can go for:

1. Client-side performance testing, i.e. how fast is rendering, scripts efficiency, etc. For this you don't need more than 1 browser /  virtual user, you can use your favorite [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) which have `Performance` / `Audit` tabs where you can [analyze your request timeline](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference) and identify the slowest parts
2. Server-side performance testing. This exercise focuses solely on the application under test performance and gives you the insight regarding how many concurrent users your application can handle providing acceptable response time / throughput. You don't need any browser for this as browsers don't do any magic, they just send [HTTP requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) and render the responses. You can mimic the same behavior using JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, just make sure to perform the associated configuration so [requests originating from JMeter would look like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) in terms of handling embedded resources, cookies, headers, cache, AJAX requests, etc.

   Protocol-based approach has much less CPU/Memory footprint therefore you can mimic thousands of users from a mid-range modern laptop (assuming your follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)). Check out [WebDriver Sampler Tutorial](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/)

   > Note: It is NOT the intention of this project to replace the HTTP Samplers included in JMeter. Rather it is meant to compliment them by measuring the end user load time.

   Assuming all above you should be focusing on creating the load using HTTP Request samplers and use 1-2 WebDriver Samplers to measure client-side performance (for example using [Navigation Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API)) if needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I want to be able to interact with elements on the page as part of load testing, but am I right in thinking that's not really possible on a large scale?

Comment: If "interaction with elements" doesn't cause a network request - you will be able to measure it using approach from point 1, otherwise you will be able to simulate it using the approach from point 2